# is Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer exam is no longer available?

Tags: magento2, certification

Can anyone please let me know is Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer exam is available, I can see there is no exam at https://u.Magento.com/certification

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because , Exam is avaliable so this question has no meaning

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 Certified Professional exam is available now,

They removed this exam yesterday because some wrong cart rule applied for mage-tituns Mexico.

So that's why exam was not there

Answer (score 0):

You can check it here - https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer#.WrH3MnaYO1s.

I am not sure why its not being listed on that page.

Comment: The page exists, bud it is not possible to purchase the voucher. Also vouchers in existing carts are gone :/

Comment: Seems its now out of stock

Answer (score 0):

`Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer` exam is available. You can check using the below link:

https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer